# Unsatisfied link running program with closed source JNI library (armv5) on Raspberry Pi (armv6)

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, raspberry-pi, armv6

I must use a third-party closed-source library in a project for the Raspberry Pi running Linux. 
The problem is that the library is compiled for android on `armv5te`, while the Raspberry pi has `armv6` architecture. The library is a compiled C/C++ library.

I thought that `armv6` should have backwards compatibility to `armv5` and `android` is in its core `linux`, right?

When I try to run my program, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so: /usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht Ã¶ffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1953)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1878)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1868)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
        at de.feig.FedmIscReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at FeigReader.addr_add(FeigReader.java:12)
        at ReaderPoll.main(ReaderPoll.java:8)
```

The path /usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so is the correct path where the library is.
I have the same program running on a x86 without any problems.

Now is this due to a architecture incompatibility, or have I missed some configuration on the pi perhaps? Also does anybody see a workaround here?

Thanks

Comment: What do your compile flags look like for the ndk?

Comment: Is the Pi running android? If not then you're probably running into, at a minimum, the issue that the library is referencing a program interpreter that's not on the Pi, which causes the 'file not found' issue. You may be able to work around it by creating a symlink from the interpreter that the library is looking for and the one that's present on the Pi. You can determine the interpreter using `readelf -l libandrdoid.so` - it's the line mentioning `Requesting program interpreter` and the path in square brackets. It still may not work because it may not be binary compatible.

Comment: @sager89 i don't compile it, it is precompiled and i don't have the source code

Comment: @Petesh really interesting thought, but since the .so i'm calling written in C/C++, there is no such line. Also the Pi is not running android. I will clarify that in my Question.

Comment: @mrblack My bad on the original comment - libraries generally don't have an interpreter. Can you check on the pi that all the dependent libraries of `/usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so` are present? i.e. do an `ldd /usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so`. You'll get the `no such file or directory` if dependent libraries are missing.

Comment: @Petesh ok, thanks. I think i see the problem now more clearly. ldd /usr/lib/libobidisc4j.so gives me 'not a dynamic executable'. So the problem here is probably that android librarys are meant to deployed differntly, i.e. in a .apk? I will open another more general question for that.